# using these sentences in a letter of intent

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage

Are these sentences suitable for a letter of intent:

1- .... is to become an expert in my field **through proceeding for the doctoral studies.**

2-A great example of **such an approach** came just this month from ......

3- I look forward to **establishing successful innovative collaborations** with .......

Comment: Welcome to English Langauge and Usage. Questions about proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?") are generally considerd off-topic, unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified.

Comment: I am sorry. I will pay attention next times :).

Comment: I need an answer to my questions. where can I post these questions? I can't understand why it is on hold while one member was so helpful to correct the mistakes! :( .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is grammatically incorrect. I'm not sure I can articulate why except to say that the phrase is not idiomatic academic English. For example, "proceeding" is usually a word used for physical movement rather than progress in one's studies, "for" is not the right preposition in this context, and "the" is used in a situation where "doctoral studies" doesn't take a definite article. Good alternatives to the highlighted language would be "by pursuing a doctoral degree" or "undertaking doctoral studies."

The second example is fine. Unless you are pursuing your studies with someone with a strong commitment to plain English language in legal or official publications (who don't like it when people use the word "such" in the manner that you do), the reader would find the use perfectly normal and easy to understand. In other disciplines, this usage would be preferred.

The third example is a bit gushing and vapid, but it is not incorrect or necessarily inappropriate. I would probably drop the word "successful" which is implied by the other words in this context. Too many modifiers in a phrase can seem excessive and insincere.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation. so for the...
1- First sentence: 
Suggestion:
My goal in joining a graduate program is to become an expert in my field by pursuing a doctoral degree
2- Second sentence:
It is correct as long as "such an approach" refers to a certain approach mentioned before. 

3- Third sentence:
suggestion:
I look forward to establishing innovative collaborations with a multidisciplinary research team that can ....

Comment: Much better than the original.

Comment: Should I say:
....pursuing a doctoral degree in public health ? or .... the doctoral degree in ... ? or neither of them ?

Comment: The former, "a doctoral degree in public health." or "a doctorate in public health" or "a PhD in public health."

Comment: Thank you so much!. My last question which is definetly off-topic but I am running out of time : Should I include my address and the department addess at the top left in my letter ? even when the form will be submitted electronically. It takes at least 15% of the one-page letter of intent.

Comment: Absolutely include your address. If you must omit anything out of space consideration, omit the address of the department as the reader obviously already knows that. But if you have space, including an inside address is preferred.

Comment: Thanks! You have been of a great help!. This is my first contribution to stachexchange.com and I don't know why they put the topic on hold.